# Android Object Serializes itself from method

Tags: java, android, gson, android-sharedpreferences

I need and object containing my settings in primitive types to be able to load and save from and to the Android shared preferences by calling a load or save method from the object.

I have created a class called thePreferences.java, this class has a few primitive fields. I have created 2x methods within this class to load and save this class from and to the sharedPreferences. See below the code used in my class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class thePreferences extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {

    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "thePreferences";
    private static final String PREF_TEXT = "pref_text";
    public static final String TAG = "WPC";

    public boolean loggedIn = false;
    public int deviceId = 0;
    public int userId = 0;
    public String email = "";
    public String deviceAlias = "";

    public thePreferences() {
    }

    public thePreferences(boolean loggedIn, int deviceId, int userId, String email, String deviceAlias) {
        this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.email = email;
        this.deviceAlias = deviceAlias;
    }


    public boolean loadThePreferences(Context c) {

        SharedPreferences pref = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (pref.contains(PREF_TEXT)) {
            String theJson = pref.getString(PREF_TEXT, null);
            Log.i(TAG, "The JSON string loaded from Shared Preferences : " + theJson);
            thePreferences p = new Gson().fromJson(theJson, thePreferences.class);
            this.deviceAlias = (p.deviceAlias);
            this.deviceId = (p.deviceId);
            this.email = (p.email);
            this.loggedIn = (p.loggedIn);
            return true;

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Could not load SharedPreferences, value does not exist.");
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static boolean saveThePreferences(Context c,thePreferences p){

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String theJson = gson.toJson(p);
        c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putString(PREF_TEXT,theJson)
                .commit();

        return true;
    }




    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "thePreferences{" +
                "loggedIn=" + this.loggedIn +
                ", deviceId=" + this.deviceId +
                ", userId=" + this.userId +
                ", email='" + this.email + '\'' +
                ", deviceAlias='" + this.deviceAlias + '\'' +
                '}';
    }


}
```

I then try to call this from another activity to load and save the preferences as follow:

```
contextOfApplication = getApplicationContext();
thePreferences preferencesObj = new thePreferences(true,12345,552441,"abc@123.com","theDeivceAlias");
preferencesObj.saveThePreferences(contextOfApplication,preferencesObj);

preferencesObj.loadThePreferences(contextOfApplication);
```

I cannot get it to execute past the saveThePreferences() method. It keep on crashin with a StackOverflow exeption and I cannot figure out why.'

Can someone please advise if there is another way of doing this or maybe where I have gone wrong?

Thank in advance

Comment: At first, thePreferences is a class therefore by convention should start with a capital letter. Next, you should NOT try to serialize a whole activity. Instead, try to store your data that you need as primitive types and also get them as primitve types. To save your entire class as a json string does not makes sense here.

Comment: Thanks, I do not want to serialise the whole activity but only the object instance of my class, which contains only primitive fields. Based on the GSON documentation here: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the prefernecesObj into itself

```
preferencesObj.saveThePreferences(contextOfApplication,preferencesObj);
```

Change the function to:

```
public boolean saveThePreferences(Context c){

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String theJson = gson.toJson(this);
    c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit()
            .putString(PREF_TEXT,theJson)
            .commit();

    return true;
}
```

then call like this:

```
preferencesObj.saveThePreferences(contextOfApplication);
```

Answer (score 3):

At first, thePreferences is a class therefore by convention should start with a capital letter.

Next, you should NOT try to serialize a whole activity. Instead, try to store your data that you need as primitive types and also get them as primitve types. To save your entire class as a json string does not makes sense here.

One way to do:

1. Create a new class which only purpose is to load and save the data you need.
   (Like your thePreferences, but make it a simple class with no inheritance of an activity).
2. The new class holds the preference name and keys as static strings.
3. Instantiate the new class with a context and preload the shared preferences as a final member
4. provide load and set methods for the single values you need
5. Use this class inside of your activities as a member or method locale variable

Ps.: Remove gson and serializable stuff

Edit: If you really want to store your data as a json string, then the sharedPreferences are not the util to use. I can not recommend to do this, but then you should send your data to a server or store it on the external data storage (sd card etc).